# Word for when a precursor shares a name with its product

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word the describes the relationship between a precursor and its product when they share the same name, at least colloquially. For instance, the beverage coffee and the grounds that it is made from. We refer to both as "coffee" but context gives us the literal meaning. The same is true for "tea" as it is both the dried leaves *and* the drink made by steeping said leaves.

I can't find any other examples of this relationship, though I wouldn't be surprised if there were some. It feels a lot like a synecdoche but that perhaps doesn't encompass the entire concept.

Comment: I'm not sure coffee and tea have the same before/after names for quite the reason of your observation.  In both examples, the way we consume the item is to prepare it as a beverage.  We sometimes refer to the beverage as "brewed coffee" or "brewed tea".  I think referring to the beverage by simply its "source" name is a shortening for simplification.  So the applicable term would be a generic language term for shortening, rather than a term that means the source product and the resulting product have the same name.

Comment: OTOH: "Waiter, my coffee tastes like dirt!"  "Well, that's understandable.  It was ground just this morning."

Comment: There are loads of words in this category - ***wood*** (first a small forest, then a construction material), ***roast*** (first a cooking method, then the meal itself). Informally, a ***smoke*** starts out as a cigarette, then it goes up in smoke / becomes an atmospheric haze. But I doubt anyone has ever needed to coin a grammatical term for the class of words that have this characteristic.

Comment: It seems like just another variety of *metonym*, but there's probably no specific term for this form.

Comment: You're no thinking of eponymous are you?

Comment: I don't think so. *Eponymous* seems to specifically relate between people and things. It could definitely be an example of *metonymy*.

Comment: I would say coffee (beverage) and coffee (plant, bean or ground up beans) are one word with *related meanings*.  I'm not writing an answer because I don't know how to document this. // I think *grounds* means the ground up beans *after* they've been used to brew the beverage.

Comment: It's tough. Colloquially (and even formally), the *ground* coffee is occasionally referred to as "grounds"[1] even though, yes, you're right, the word is defined as the used material. And yes, the words are related, I was just hoping to discover that there's a word to describe their relationship.

[1] From Wikipedia - "...is made by letting hot water drip onto coffee grounds..."

Comment: @FumbleFingers They both go back to Old English, but the [*OED* entry for 'wood'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230005) has the obsolete sense of a single tree as the original definition, rather than its sense of a copse. Assuming they're right, the metonymy of wood for things made from trees would have developed in parallel with (rather than from) the sense of a small forest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As above, it's really just an example of

## [metonymy](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117628)

in action: *a substituted name; the substitution of a property or associated object for something's original name.*

If you wanted to coin a term for this specific subset, you could go with (**a**)**etionym** with the sense *a name for a finished product derived from the originating substance, as tea, coffee, bronze, jade, &c*.